# How do I get Python 2.7 to accept multiple variable inputs on a single line

Tags: python, variables, input

Im trying to get the user to input the length and width of a rectangle at the same time.

```
length,width = float (raw_input("What is the length and width? ")).split(',')
```

When I run the program, however, and enter two variables such as 3,5 I get an error saying that I have an invalid literal for type float().

Comment: Can you make sure that this is the exact code that you're trying to run?  Right now, this code is going to give a syntax error because you're missing a `"` on your prompt string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why does this fail:

```
float (raw_input("What is the length and width? ")).split(',')
```

The `split(',')` splits a string into a sequence of strings. You can't call `float` on a sequence of strings, only on a single string. That's why the error says it's "an invalid literal for type float".

If you want to call the same function on every value in a sequence, there are two ways to do it:

Use a list comprehension (or a generator expression):

```
[float(x) for x in raw_input("What is the length and width? ")).split(',')]
```

Or the `map` function:

```
map(float, raw_input("What is the length and width? ")).split(','))
```

I would use the list comprehension, because that's what the BDFL prefers, and because it's simpler for other things you may want to do like `x[2]`, but it really doesn't matter that much in this case; it's simple enough either way, and you should learn what both of them mean.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's because you're entering two numbers separated by a comma, but splitting that value on a period. Split it on a comma and it should work much better.

Comment: That was an error in what I typed rather than what my actual code is. The question is up to date and edited

Answer (score 1):

You also will probably want to cast to integers:

```
prompt = "what is the length and width? "
inpt = raw_input(prompt)
length, width = [int(i) for i in inpt.split(',')]
```

Comment: Actually floats but I assume i can just change the int() to float()

Comment: Yep. You might also want to let the user know it needs to be comma-separated, and check the length of inpt.split(',') to verify exactly two numbers were entered.